# Xamarin.Android: ProgressDialog does not show up

Tags: android, android-asynctask, xamarin.android, async-await, progressdialog

I have problems with showing up a **ProgressDialog**:

The following snippet shows my code in an example:

```
public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Context);
    progressDialog.SetCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.SetMessage("Saving ...");
}


private void Method()
{
    progressDialog.Show();

    var testDialog = progressDialog.IsShowing;

    SaveImage();
}


private void SaveImage()
{
    // does lot 
    ...
    // especially this method takes some time
    mutableBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
}
```

I create a ProgressDialog, which I want to show before calling the *SaveImage* Method (and Cancel it when *SaveImage* is done).

My problem is that the ProgressDialog will not be displayed until the *SaveImage* Method is done.

In Debug-Mode, **progressDialog.IsShowing** is **true**, before the *SaveImage*-Method is called, but it is not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works fine for me:

```
private async void Method()
{
    progressDialog.Show();

    var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
    {
        SaveImage();
    }));
    thread.Start();

    while(thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }

    progressDialog.Dismiss();
}
```

Meanwhile, I outsourced this code into a `public static class ThreadHelper`, that just takes an Action (in this case *SaveImage()*) and a ProgressDialog as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to shift your IO related code to a background thread, you can use an asynctask for this

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private String resp;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    saveImage();
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(),
            "ProgressDialog",
            "Loading");
}
}
```

Comment: i am working on a DialogFragment, how can i get my Context here

Comment: Hi, @K.Dexter. The property `Activity` is your `Context`, or you can use Construction method， like public AsyncTaskRunner(Context c){}.

Comment: DialogFragment has its own context. You can just use getContext(). I have edited my answer